# True definition of Biology

Tags: general-biology

I just started biology and im pretty clueless on what it really means. So before you vote this question down, can you tell me what it really means.

P.S. Is plate tectonics related to biology? or Chemistry? or Physics?

Comment: Typing "biology" into google turns up an adequate definition so in its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please 
take a look at the [How to Ask](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/asking) 
page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution or showing research. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: Every expert will give a different answer on this depending on their own experiences in studying a biological features. The fact you're asking about plate tectonics in the same question makes me wonder if you've even bothered googling any of these terms. Try [this link](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=what+is+biology).

Comment: In which class do you read? since you just started; so I guess you are in class 4, 5 or 6. Is that? [Biology](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biology) means study about living organisms. (( Etymology: greek *Bios* (= life) + *logos* (=discussion) )). It is also known in many other names such as [Life-science](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/life+science), Life science**s**, Biological science**s**, etc.  But they are same.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused just FYI, there are different "grades" (as they're called in the US) in different parts of the world. I don't know if your "class 4" is the same as my "grade 4". Simply asking the OP's age would be a better way of going about it.

Comment: Though this question too-basic; thereis one significance; the approach we  break the world into "physics", "chemistry", "geology", "mathematics" etc. just to sort information. But in nature all they exist together and are interrelated. We can't think biology without chemistry (because we're made of atoms). Similarly we cant think biology without geology since we live on Earth and our history is mixed with origin, changes and structure of Earth. Similarly mathematics since to comprehend any process it is urgent, The approach "mad guy asking biology question to chemistry teacher hehe" is wrong

Comment: @MattDMo ok I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Now I could understand significance of this meta post http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/biology-se-and-professional-biologists/3468#3468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the definition of Biology as given by [Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/biology?s=t):

- the study of living organisms, divided into many specialized fields that cover their morphology, physiology, anatomy, behavior, origin, and distribution.

Tectonic plates are not living, thus it isn't biology. 
It would be Geology:

- Geology is the study of the Earth, the materials of which it is made, the structure of those materials, and the processes acting upon them

Source: [Geology.com](http://geology.com/articles/what-is-geology.shtml)

Comment: If you have criticisms or concerns about the question, please put them in comments, not an answer. You may use several comments if necessary. See [this discussion](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/3357/on-answers-that-are-basically-extended-comments) on meta for more.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you for your constructive comment. I have updated my answer to better serve the OP and eliminate any criticism.